# How to make all properties optional in a Zod schema based on a specific product availability flag?

Tags: javascript, typescript, validation, schema, zod

I have a Zod schema that validates product properties for an e-commerce application. In my schema, I currently have a property called `isLimitedEdition` which indicates whether a product is available in limited quantities. However, when `isLimitedEdition` is set to true, I want all other properties in the schema to become optional.

Here's the existing schema structure:

```
const productProperties = z.object({
  name: z.string().nonempty(),
  description: z.string().nonempty(),
  price: z.number().positive(),
  category: z.string().nonempty(),
  brand: z.string().nonempty(),
  isFeatured: z.boolean().default(false),
  isLimitedEdition: z.boolean().default(false),
});
```

In this schema, I want to achieve a behavior where all properties (name, description, price, category, brand, isFeatured) become optional if isLimitedEdition is set to true.

How can I modify this schema to achieve the desired behavior? I would appreciate any guidance or code examples to help me implement this logic correctly. Thank you in advance!

I tried the `refine` method but it didn't work

Comment: You could use `z.discriminatedUnion` with `isLimitedEdition` as the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `discriminatedUnion`:

```
const productProperties = z.object({
  name: z.string().nonempty(),
  description: z.string().nonempty(),
  price: z.number().positive(),
  category: z.string().nonempty(),
  brand: z.string().nonempty(),
  isFeatured: z.boolean().default(false),
})

const product = z.discriminatedUnion('isLimitedEdition', [
  productProperties.extend({ isLimitedEdition: z.literal(false) }),
  productProperties.partial().extend({ isLimitedEdition: z.literal(true) }),
])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).